# No connection is available to service this operation: when using Azure Redis Cache

Tags: c#, azure, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I have the following code which I use to get information from the cache.  I dont know if maybe my app is opening too many connections or just this error is due to a transient failure on azure redis cache.

This is the stack trace

> [RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this
>   operation: GET UserProfileInformation|globaladmin@xx.onmicrosoft.com] 
>   StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl(Message
>   message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:1922
>   StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync(Message message,
>   ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisBase.cs:80
>   StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.StringGet(RedisKey key, CommandFlags
>   flags) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:1431
>   xx.Utils.SampleStackExchangeRedisExtensions.Get(IDatabase cache,
>   String key) in
>   C:\Proyectos\xx\xx\Utils\SampleStackExchangeRedisExtensions.cs:20
>   xx.Cache.UserProfile.GetUserProfile(String identityname) in
>   C:\Proyectos\xx\xx\Cache\UserProfile.cs:22
>   x.Controllers.UserProfileController.GetPropertiesForUser() in
>   C:\Proyectos\xx\xx\Controllers\UserProfileController.cs:16
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +61
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14

And this is the code

```
   public static Models.UserProfile GetUserProfile(string identityname)
        {
            /// It needs to be cached for every user because every user can have different modules enabled.

            var cachekeyname = "UserProfileInformation|" + identityname;
            IDatabase cache = CacheConnectionHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
            Models.UserProfile userProfile = new Models.UserProfile();
            object obj = cache.Get(cachekeyname);
            string userProfileString;
            if (obj != null)
            {
                //get string from cache
                userProfileString = obj.ToString();

                //conver string to our object
                userProfile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.UserProfile>(userProfileString);
                return userProfile;
            }
            else
            {
                #region Get User Profile from AD
                Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(SettingsHelper.AzureAdGraphApiEndPoint);
                var token = AppToken.GetAppToken();

                ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
                 serviceRoot,
                 async () => await AppToken.GetAppTokenAsync());

                string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

                Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Application app = (Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Application)adClient.Applications.Where(
                    a => a.AppId == SettingsHelper.ClientId).ExecuteSingleAsync().Result;
                if (app == null)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Unable to get a reference to application in Azure AD.");
                }

                string requestUrl = string.Format("https://graph.windows.net/{0}/users/{1}?api-version=1.5", SettingsHelper.Tenant, identityname);
                HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
                hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                HttpResponseMessage hrm = hc.GetAsync(new Uri(requestUrl)).Result;

                if (hrm.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Models.UserProfile currentUserProfile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.UserProfile>(hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

                    //convert object to json string
                    userProfileString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentUserProfile);

                    cache.Set(cachekeyname, userProfileString, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SettingsHelper.CacheUserProfileMinutes));
                    return currentUserProfile;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
                #endregion
            }
        }




public static class SampleStackExchangeRedisExtensions
    {
        public static T Get<T>(this IDatabase cache, string key)
        {
            return Deserialize<T>(cache.StringGet(key));
        }

        public static object Get(this IDatabase cache, string key)
        {
            return Deserialize<object>(cache.StringGet(key));
        }

        public static void Set(this IDatabase cache, string key, object value, TimeSpan expiration)
        {
            cache.StringSet(key, Serialize(value), expiration);
        }

        static byte[] Serialize(object o)
        {
            if (o == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, o);
                byte[] objectDataAsStream = memoryStream.ToArray();
                return objectDataAsStream;
            }
        }

        static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] stream)
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            if (stream == null)
                return default(T);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(stream))
            {
                T result = (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
                return result;
            }
        }
```

Questions are:
1. How can I control a connection exception like the one shown, so that the user doesnt get the error and instead it goes to the DB if redis is unavailable?
2. Is there anyway to retry with transient fault handling for azure redis cache?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe these are transient errors. I have seen many of these in my application logs before I implemented simple retry logic. I also had quite a few timeouts. Very simple retry logic, plus adding `syncTimeout=3000` to redis connection string resolved **all** these for me.

```
public object Get(string key)
{
    return Deserialize(Cache.StringGet(key));
}

public object GetWithRetry(string key, int wait, int retryCount)
{
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            return Get(key);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (i < retryCount + 1)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(wait);
                i++;
            }
            else throw;
        }
    }
    while (i < retryCount + 1);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As Rouen suggests, these are probably transient connection errors. Here's a full async example using [Polly](https://github.com/michael-wolfenden/Polly) to handle the retries.

```
        var value = await Policy 
            .Handle<RedisConnectionException>() // Possible network issue 
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)) // retry 3 times, with a 3 second delay, before giving up
            .ExecuteAsync(async () => {
                return await cache.StringGetAsync(key);
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Also Stack Exchange client has in built retry logic where the client will retry itself. Here is some more information about the configuration options.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-faq/#what-do-the-stackexchangeredis-configuration-options-do

Comment: That retry logic seems to be related to establishing the connection, not performing get/set requests.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [Polly](https://github.com/michael-wolfenden/Polly) in my Cache Repository to retry all operation with this exception. I tried Retry method from Polly, but this wrong decision and now I'm using WaitAndRetry. With this method you can retry operation with some sleep time - with this you can queue operation to Redis

Answer (score 1):

Update your redis nuget package to latest version and it should resolve your problem as it did mine!

Comment: Exactly - one should try this first :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Azure's redis cache, check to see if you're on the basic tier. If so, **you'll get this message any time Microsoft updates your server** (I found this to happen every few weeks).

A sample of my exact error message:

> No connection is active/available to service this operation: GET
> 43da9f64-da42-4281-845b-82a7d2b7f400#Settings; It was not possible to
> connect to the redis server(s). Error connecting right now. To allow
> this multiplexer to continue retrying until it's able to connect, use
> abortConnect=false in your connection string or
> AbortOnConnectFail=false; in your code. ConnectTimeout, mc: 1/1/0,
> mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: RDA04A5E790CA0, IOCP:
> (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER:
> (Busy=0,Free=32767,Min=2,Max=32767), v: 2.2.4.27433 It was not
> possible to connect to the redis server(s). Error connecting right
> now. To allow this multiplexer to continue retrying until it's able to
> connect, use abortConnect=false in your connection string or
> AbortOnConnectFail=false; in your code. ConnectTimeout

The screenshot below, shown after running automated diagnostics in Azure, was the smoking gun. Some recommendation highlights:

- Upgrade to the standard tier or above to resolve the issue.
- Implement a retry policy to hide the issue.
- Set an update schedule to mitigate issue damage.

[image: Microsoft suggestions for redis maintenance downtime]

Answer (score 0):

Hosting on Azure with Azure Cache for Redis - the only change I did to fix this error was to **add `,sslprotocols=tls12` at the end of the connection string** that's provided by Azure.

I also updated to the latest version of StackExchange.Redis 2.2.88 but I'm not sure if that has any relevance to this. (probably not)

Found the answer in [this GitHub post](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1120#issuecomment-991669435).